# Xamarin Forms Android Jar Binding Issue on Release Build

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

We are building an app that can connect to bluetooth printer. We can bind the JAR [refer to Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar) from the printer vendor [Jar download link](https://downloads.puqulabel.com/softs/q00q20q30q40.zip) and successfully build and run on Debug mode.

But when we do Release build, it show the below error and fail `com.android.tools.build.bundletool.model.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$FileUsesReservedNameException: File 'root/res/values/DzPrinter_config.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.`

We try to change the Jar from **EmbeddedJar** to **InputJar** which can successfully build but apps will show class not found exception.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you try to set .jar build action as **EmbeddedReferenceJar** and try it again on release mode.

Comment: sadly it become Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Dothantech' does not exist in the namespace 'Com' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234)